# GUI way to access sqlite database on Android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

It there a more GUI oriented way (like SQL Server Management Studio or phpMyAdmin) of accessing sqlite database (view/change table structure, running test queries) in android emulator?

P.S. I know only one way to get there. This is through adb -> emulator shell -> sqlite

Answer (score 0):

So far I found only partial solution. 
With the help of file explorer in Android Monitor I export db file to host computer and then open database with SqliteBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I just discovered sqlitestudio.pl (I'm unaffiliated with this product). They link to a video that shows this in action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFKLGsfpwNc.